# Why is my video undefined?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to reference my `var video` in my nested `setInterval` function below. It is showing as 'undefined' in my console when the video is played.

Any help on correctly passing this element to this nested function?

```
var video = $("video");
video.on("play", function() {
  console.log(this.currentTime);
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log(video.currentTime);
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: @tobiq, it did not fix my problem.

Comment: does `console.log(this.currentTime);` work?

Answer (score 2):

Your video variable is a jquery object, you can fix this by harnessing the DOM element by either changing the variable decleration to:

```
var video = $("video")[0];
```

or changing the use of video to

```
video[0].currentTime();
```